# Couldn't find an element with Selenium 2 by xpath

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, selenium, xpath

I need to find this element in HTML

```
<input id="hidder_form:j_idt286:parnterCategoryId" name="hidder_form:j_idt286:parnterCategoryId" type="text" value="" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-multiline="false">
```

And I'm doing it like this

Using XPATH, generated by Chrome Console:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="hidder_form:j_idt286:parnterCategoryId"])))
```

Using XPATH, which is looking for kind of regular expression:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[starts-with(@id, "hidder_form") and ends-with(@id, "parnterCategoryId")]')))
```

And finally using XPATH, which goes exactly to my element through the page

```
'/html/body/section[@id = "hidder"]/form[@id="hidder_form"]/div[@id="forms"]/div[@class="ui-outputpanel ui-widget"]/section[@id="category_edit_form"]/div[@class="column-container"]/div[@class="left column50per"]/fieldset[@class = "properties"]/div/input[ends-with(@id, "parnterCategoryId")]'
```

None of them is working. All gives an exception

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: u'The given selector Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression because of the following error:\nSyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: Is the id of the element dynamic at all?

Comment: Yes, i think it has dynamic part between hidder_form and parnterCategoryId  id="hidder_form:j_idt286:parnterCategoryId"

Comment: Can't you find the element by id instead of by xpath?

Comment: @thepolina I suspected as much. I'm confused as to why xpath using the 'starts-with()` and `end-with()` isn't working. What happens if you change the beginning of the xpath from `//*` to `//input`?

Comment: @MarkRowlands if I change it to input it gives the same exception

Comment: @JoriO I used this statement input_element = driver.find_element_by_id('hidder_form:j_idt286:parnterCategoryId') to find an element and got an exception again.

Comment: Is the element within an `iframe`?

Comment: Nope, my HTML has no iframe at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ends-with` is an XPath 2.0 function, and your browser probably uses an XPath 1.0 processor (Selenium uses the browser processor).

XPath support: [Comparison of layout engines (XML)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28XML%29#Query_technologies)

Comment: I think you are right. I use FireFox and according to this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions) it cannot handle `ends-with()`